# what will happen when a class implement two interface having same method signature but different modifier default and static

Tags: java, java-8

```
interface A {
    default void m1() {}
}

interface B{
    static void m1() {}
}

class C implements A,B {
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `m1()` for both interfaces A and B?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you check what the specification says?

Answer (score 7):

The difference between static methods in interfaces and in classes, is that `static methods` are *not* inherited in case of interfaces.

They *are* inherited in case of classes (but are not overridable).

Default methods are overridable and inherited by `C` from interface `A` on the other hand. So, since `m1` is declared `static` in `B` it is not inherited in `C`, thus no conflict

Comment: yeah, you are right. the static method is not inherited. I lost it, :). nice captures.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to the answers given so far I will add some formal explanation.

[JLS 8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8)

> A class does not inherit static methods from its superinterfaces.

But

> A class C inherits from its direct superclass all concrete methods m
>   (both ***static*** and instance) of the superclass for which all of the
>   following are true:
>
> m is a member of the direct superclass of C.
>
> m is public, protected, or declared with package access in the same
>   package as C.
>
> No method declared in C has a signature that is a subsignature
>   (§8.4.2) of the signature of m.

So something like

```
class Super{
   public static void stM(){ }
}

interface Super2{
   static void stMFromInterface(){ }
}

class Sub extends Super implements Super2{ }
```

Now

```
Sub.stM(); // fine
Sub.stMFromInterface(); // compile error, interface static method not visible
```

In case of interfaces, static methods are not inherited also.

[JLS 9.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1)

> An interface does not inherit static methods from its superinterfaces.

```
public interface Super {
    static void st(){ }
}

public interface Sub extends Super {
}

Sub.st(); //compile error
```

Comment: the static method of the interface is standalone. so the static method in interface is not inherited by any types. the first is not completely right.

Comment: @holi-java Can you please clarify the meaning of standalone? JLS specifies it pretty much clear that static methods of superinterfaces are not inherited by classes.

Comment: I means that it is a partial answer, :). the static methods is also not inherited by enum, interface, class, annotations.

Comment: @holi-java Have to agree. Added some more explanation.

Comment: I already upvote yours, :). it is just my opnion, since I lost it at the first time. after read the JLS I found the static method in interface is standalone.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to call both methods:

```
class C implements A,B {   
    public void test ()
    {
        B.m1(); // calls the static method of interface B
        m1(); // calls the default method of interface A
    }
}
```

Of course, calling `B.m1()` would be possible even if class `C` does not implement `B`.